# How to check if an executable or any of its libraries has been changed with Python

Tags: python

I use some python scripts to test changes I make to a (external) program written in C++. I have several versions of this external program and I have to compare the output of these versions. As the external program takes rather long to run, I'd like to run only those versions which have been changed since the last run of my test. So I need a way to check if the program (or any of its library) has changed.

As I am working under Linux, I suppose I could call 'ldd' and by (recursively) parsing the output, I would get a list of all linked libraries. If I then calculate a hashsum over the program and all the libraries, I probably could get a value which tells me if the program has changed or not.

Now I'd like to know if this is a suitable way and if there is a better (more pythonic) way, probably without having to use the external tool ldd.

Comment: Well, can't you do like `make` and other such tools do it? check that the last-modified timestamp of the executable is after the last-modified timestamp for the sources/libraries etc.

Comment: There is no built-in support for ldd-like functionality in Python, and I wouldn't consider it worth implementing either. There is nothing wrong with your sketched approach, go for it. And I'd prefer md5 over mtime, it's more tamper/accident-proof.

Comment: That would probably be faster than calculating the hashsums. However, I still have to find all the libraries (or sources) with a tool like ldd. If possible, I'd rather find a way how to do it in python without calling external tools.